# Execution of interactive command in remote Powershell session not working

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-access

I am having troubles executing commands in a remote PowerShell session which need user interaction.

Example: I enter a remote session

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName mobius
```

In this session I execute a command which asks for a password:

```
[mobius]: PS C:\Windows\system32> & 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\plink.exe' merlin -l joe

joe@merlin's password:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\plink.exe : Using username "plakat".
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Using username "plakat".:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

The last two lines are displayed in red. There seem to be two problems.

**Problem 1:** plink.exe writes the text 'Using username "plakat"' to stderr. This probably causes the error message. Can I suppress this somehow? (pipe stderr to stdout or something.)

**Problem 2:** The process exits at the point where I should enter the password. I can also reproduce that with other commands like

```
[mobius]: PS C:\Windows\system32> cmd /c date
```

It does not let me enter a date. Both commands work if I run them in a local PowerShell. Neither Problem 1 or 2 are showing in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interactive native windows console commands are not supported in a remote powershell session. I know this sounds dumb, but currently this is the case (as of PowerShell v4.0).

Most command line utilities support some form of automation, be it piping or passing values as arguments so take a closer look at the tools you're using. Of course this is on a case by case basis. There is no easy way to intercept an interactive prompt on the remote end in any universal manner.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm. I was afraid of that. In my example I can use plink with public-key authentication to circumvent the password prompt. But that only shifts my problem. Because my final goal is to open an interactive ssh session to a third machine with plink (which is a command line ssh client). I find it somehow strange that this is not possible. What if I would like to edit a file on the remote server or use an interactive command line debugger?

Comment: Editing text files on remote servers is a distinctly unix-like activity for administrators. In the Windows world, APIs are king, and are usually remotable (wmi, dcom, winrm/soap). Any debugger worth its salt can connect to a remote server. Command line debuggers at that are rare: I only know of two, one of which is never used remotely (outside of a serial connection.) -- CDB and MDBG.

Comment: So, just to add to that wall of text, if you want remote interactivity then install an SSH server.

Comment: Since it does not seem to be possible, I accept this as answer. I did in fact install a SSH server. 

It's funny though, that MS went so far, but did not go the whole length. Why have a command like _Enter-PSSession_ which opens an **interactive** remote session, but does not allow much interactivity? Hopefully in future versions they will implement it...

Comment: @gwodus I agree - it doesn't work with native commands that try to interact with the user. interactive cmdlets work fine.

Comment: And just to add to @x0n's addition, alternatively you can achieve remote interactivity with `psexec \\computername cmd` if you have the SysInternals PSTools suite. I went this route after needing to use a command that prompts for confirmation, and does not include a `/Y` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can sidestep the issue by using *Invoke-command* cmdlet which executes and exits

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName Mobius -ScriptBlock {## your stuff}`

and combine it with pipe so in the case of the date command

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName Mobius -ScriptBlock {echo "01-02-1999" |cmd /c date}`

or for plink

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Mobius -ScriptBlock {"yourpassword"| &'c:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\plink.exe' merlin -l joe `"bashcommand1 && bashcommand2`" }
```

or even simpler

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Mobius -ScriptBlock { &'c:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\plink.exe' merlin -l joe -pw yourpass `"bashcommand1 && bashcommand2`" }
```

but as @X0n said no real interactivity.

Comment: Like I said in a comment to X0n's answer. The password was not really my problem. I still needed real interactivity further on. But thanks for the tip. I might need some piping like you did for some smaller scripted remote tasks.